# Could the universe or any event within it have occurred otherwise, even if determinism was false?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, determinism

Could any event have happened differently? Even if the universe was “inherently stochastic”, does this imply that events could have occurred differently? It seems to me that even inherent randomness would just result in true unpredictability in the future but nothing further would be implied.

Even if determinism was false and knowing every possible parameter and cause did not lead to complete knowledge of the future, would this actually imply that the way events turned out could have happened otherwise?

Comment: Technically, no. [Metaphysical fatalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fatalism/) does not have to be implemented through causal determinism, although it is currently the only version with any following. The reason is that alternatives have a distinct flavor of mysticism, *a la* inexplicable fate or divine predestination.

Comment: What occurs does not depend on determinism but vice versa.

Comment: Determinism is neither false nor true. Determinism is not a theory or a statement, just an abstract idea with no truth value.

Comment: What does the OP mean by "could"? Metaphysical possibility? Logical possibility? Epistemic possibility? Generic possibility?

Comment: Perhaps we should use a coin to find out.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, "Is there an [accessible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessibility_relation) world, accessible from ours that is, such that determinism is false in our world and in the accessible world things occur that don't occur in ours?" then I don't know that determinism has much bearing on this (if the other world contained the same exact sequence of events, and neither that world nor ours contained said sequence on account of determinism, I'm not sure how determinism is accessibly relevant).

You could move up to another level and ask, "Is there a world accessible from ours where determinism is false?" or then, "Do all worlds accessible from ours, even if they are nondeterministic worlds, contain the same exact events?"

If you mean, "Is it necessary that the events that have occurred, are the events that they are, regardless of determinism?" then in one sense yes, in another sense no: an event has to be what it is relative to its internal identity, but what events exist in the first place is not *per se* decided by external necessity such that different events could not have occurred.

It would also be helpful to include some reference-fixing for the word "determinism." The generic sense is mathematical: if you have a sequence of variables *x* over times *t*<sub>*n*</sub>, the value of *x* at *t*<sub>*n*</sub> is the source of the assignment of value to *x* at *t*<sub>*n*+1</sub>, e.g. if *x*<sub>*t*<sub>1</sub></sub> = 1, then there is some *f*(*x*) such that *f*(1<sub>1</sub>) changes the upper 1 to something else as the lower 1 increases, etc. If *f*(*x*) can map specific inputs to only one output per case, strict determinism is indicated. But so whether *f*(*x*) can on some other metaphysical level be itself different from time to time or world to world, is an open-ended enough (schematic) issue such that it seems trivial that two worlds could diverge with respect to *f*(*x*) and so diverge per output, ***or*** two worlds could diverge on one level but due to subtle "course corrections" (e.g. deeper *g*(*x*)'s) they end up aligned on the direct level, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The universe doesn't read philosophy journals. It does what it does, regardless of what philosophers may think.

Answer (score -1):

> Even if determinism was false [..] would this actually imply that the way events turned out could have happened otherwise?

The most common interpretation would be that yes, in that case events could have happened in different ways, and only happened the way they happened due to random factors.

But philosophically it depends on the way that determinism "was false" (or how "determinism" is defined in the question). Causal determinism is the most common meaning of "determinism". Causal determinism can be false in several ways which would still make some or all events determined by something.

Even if there were true sources of non-determinism in this universe, those could be too small, too few, too rare, too far away or too "regular" to make events turn out in different ways.

Predeterminism and fatalism are alternatives which do not necessarily require determinism. There can be more such similar nuanced theories that make events non-random yet not decided by the previous state either (but by anything else). All those could be called "Determinism without Causality".

So "events could not have turned out a different way" could be the definition of "causal and non-causal determinism". Then even if causal determinism was false, it is logically possible that non-causal determinism remains true.

Time-travelling in the science-fiction sense is one way of introducing non-causality into a universe, just to give a popular example, same as supernatural telekinesis, teleportation and such. Similarly, prophecy or otherwise "seeing" the future without inferring it from the present as in fantasy and mythology would introduce non-causality. Those could still mean that "things could not have turned out otherwise".

In physics, only quantum phenomena are considered to be possibly non-deterministic in a strict sense, even if many other events can only be described stochastically due to lack of precise measurement methods.

Comment: In short, the law of big numbers still would apply.

Comment: That is just one possible way (maybe the most obvious case, yes).

Comment: Predeterminism does require determinism. Otherwise the predeterminator could not make sure everything would proceed as planned. Fatalism requires indeterminism, otherwise Fate could not control the flow of events to reach the intended final goal. Both are imaginary ideas irrelevant in reality.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki Fatalism is a form of determinism: fate is the determinator instead of other processes.

Comment: @rus9384 Fate controls the events along the way towards a certain goal. A predeterminator designs everything beforehand and then presses PLAY.

Comment: Excellent summary.  One additional suggestion -- indeterminism in physics is only demonstrated so far in quantum phenomena, plus macro scale phenomena that are complex enough to lead to unstable equilibria.  There is an open question whether macro scale chaos phenomena are actually indeterminate, or only computationally unsolvable.  What we do know, though, is that chaos phenomena provide a methodology to leverage up quantum indeterminacy to make macro scale system indeterminate.  Triple pendulums of the triggering of cancer in a cell are examples of macro indeterminacy from quantum effects.

Comment: @Dcleve i have added a section. I am less certain about any non-determism having been proven or demonstrated. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110983/why-was-quantum-mechanics-regarded-as-a-non-deterministic-theory

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki, in the philosophic literature, predeterminism describes only the fact that things have been decided, not how they are implemented, allowing also for gods to enact decisions. See the Wikipedia article or any of the books on determinism that you have not read. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predeterminism

Comment: Hmm -- that doesn't support determinacy.  Note that every comment on the original question, plus the comment on the one reply that said that indeterminacy was up to the interpretation, DISAGREED with the claim of determinacy.  Determinate and indeterminate theories are not just interpretations, they are different theories, which Einstein forced the issue on, as he wanted to refute the supposed indeterminacy of QM.  All of Einstein's alternatives were testable, and failed testing.  As Conifold's comment noted, MWI is indeterminate, and Bohm is a different theory, called Bohmian Mechanics.

Comment: @tkruse This is hardly relevant for the question, but I stand corrected: Fate is also a god who decides everything before pressing PLAY.

Answer (score -2):

There is no "otherwise". All events have occurred *this way* instead of any other way. History is fixed, it cannot be edited, rewound or tried again. Only the future consists of uncertain possibilities.

Naturally the history *could* have turned out differently. All events in history were once mere possibilities in the future. Predetermination is a concept in religion only, not in science. A deterministic universe set up by an indeterministic *predeterminator* is an illogical, oxymoronic concept.

The current scientific consensus is that the Universe has evolved as a series of probabilistic events. Causality rules, but not with absolute accuracy. The inherent inaccuracy of all events enables evolution, the increase of entropy, the increase of complexity and the arrow of time.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but downvotes with no comments are a wasted opportunity, so if I was to guess at any issues with your answer: 1) "Naturally the history could have turned out differently". How do you know? 2) "The current scientific consensus is that the universe has evolved as a series of probabilistic events". Really? Do you have any references to support this claim? 3) "The inherent inaccuracy of all events". How can any event be accurate or inaccurate?

Comment: @Futilitarian 1) The future can turn out multiple possible ways. No reason to assume that this hasn't been the case always. 2) We have no reason to assume a divine creator. Probabilistic evolution is the only alternative to deliberate design. 3) Quantum particles have some indeterminate properties that can be expressed only as probability distributions. Therefore all measurements and predictions are approximations or averages, never exact values.

Comment: 1). My question was 'how do you know'? It doesn't help to simply restate the claim. 2) By this I assumed you were stating (by 'probabilistic') that the scientific consensus is that the universe could have evolved differently. If so, do you have any refs? 3) 'Predictions' and 'measurements' can be accurate or inaccurate as you say, but this is a different claim than your initial answer, ie. that _events_ can be too.

Comment: Re. 2). Are you  sure you're not conflating the human view of 'probability' (when assessing the likelihood of unknown future events) with _actual_ probability (whether events can unfold in any other way than the way they do?).

Comment: @Futilitarian I am talking about the mathematical probability of an event unfolding in a certain way. Probabilities are always about future events, there is no comparison with "the way they do".

Comment: Ok. But mathematical probabilities are our assessments of what might happen. This process of calculation that we undertake doesn't however tell us whether what eventuates could have somehow been different. As I've mentioned before in relation to Thinkingman's questions, theoretical physicist Sean Carroll points out that when we turn our attention to our cosmos, we are dealing with a sample size of one. We have no way of knowing whether anything could have been different.

Comment: @Futilitarian 1) I know the future has many possibilities. It is not written in stone. Never was. That's how I know. 2) My only reference is the absence of a creator god. Without random, unpredictable inaccuracies there would be no evolution. Deterministic systems don't evolve. 3) Events are inaccurate, if both cause and effect are inaccurate.

Comment: @Futilitarian Only the probability of 1 means absolute certainty, nothing else is possible. All other probabilities mean multiple possibilities. There is only one history, it is quite pointless to speculate on alternative histories, they are not possible anymore.  Let's focus on the possibilities that the future offers.

Comment: Why does the universe not being able to have occurred any other way imply determinism? It is not hard to imagine not being able to predict the future (which is what indeterminism fundamentally is) and yet still having only one way for the universe to turn out.

Comment: @thinkingman Determinism means that there are no changes allowed while the system is running. No random changes,  no deliberate changes, no predictions. Any runtime prediction would mean a deliberate change to the flow of events. A deterministic system can run only one way exactly as determined/predicted at the initial setup. Conway's Game of Life is an excellent simulation of a deterministic system. No changes are allowed after pressing RUN. Reality does accept changes, both random and deliberate. There are uncertain possibilities, incomplete knowledge and inaccurate predictions in reality.